# Update database when a selection is made in a drop down menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, post

I have no idea where to begin, so if there is already an answer out there to a question like mine I would appreciate it!  Basically the question says it all, Here is what I would like:

There is a drop down menu, simple drop down menu, nothing fancy.  When a selection is made in that drop down menu, a php mysql query is ran where the database will be updated with that value.  I have all the pieces, all I need is the code that would be able to kick it all off.

For instance when you hit submit on a form you would typically type out:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//grab information and insert into db

}
```

How would I do this for a drop down selection without having to click the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be looking for something like this

```
<form id="testform">
<select id="yourselect" name="yourselect" onChange="updateDb()">
 <option value="somevalue">Please select</option>
 <option value="somevalue1">Something</option>
</select>
</form>
```

you Javascript function will look like this

```
function updateDb() {
// I am using jquery for ajax
 $.post("yourserverhandle.php", $("#testform").serialize());
}
```

and this is how your "yourserverhandle.php" looks like

```
<?php
$query = "update yourtable set something='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["yourselect"])."' where id='something'";
.... mysql connect, execute
?>
```

Comment: Did not work, nothing happens when I make a selection in the drop down menu.

Comment: you will need to change the file names and form ID to suit you. there was one word that was misspelled which has been corrected now. In your PHP file try to print the post to troubleshoot it.
only line that you should put in your yourserverhandle.php should be print_r($_POST) to see whats coming through. make sure that path to php file is correct

Comment: here is jsfiddle view http://jsfiddle.net/q8v5g/

jsfiddle only shows how it works. You will need to change stuff as per my previous comment

Answer (score 3):

As has been said in the comments, you listen to the `onchange` event of the selectbox and either submit a form or use AJAX. This is not my point.

From a usability POV I recommend you reevaluate this proposition, if it really leads to a database update: Ever used the mouse wheel to scroll, while accidently having the focus on a selectbox? Jackpot! You just changed your DB settings without being aware of it.

So using `onchange` on a selectbox to kick off something, **that is immediately visible** is IMHO a good thing - you'll know, when you triggered it. Changing a DB setting with no feedback other than the select box changing value is IMHO a bad thing. Or an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I have everything set up to trigger, escape, do all that jazz.  I just need the form to submit when a drop down selection is made.  I tried both below methods and neither one worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#DDL_ID").change(function(){

$.ajax({
url:'/some.php',
type:'POST',
data:{submit:$(this).val()},
success:function(data){
//do something here if the server return anything
},
error:function(){
console.log("something bad happened");
}

});

});
```

on the php side

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//grab information and insert into db

}
```

P.S. always sanitize the input see [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)